# adding two webform to web site

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

I have used a webform to my drupal 7 website.And now I want to put a webform to another page(two webforms in different web pages).How can i configure webform for it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you used, webform as node, or block? If u have used, webform as block, then u goto admin/block and then configure.

From that page, you can configure, where u want the page to dispaly web form

Answer (score 0):

Create another webform just as u created the previous one.

Log in to your website with admin privileges and click on the **Add Content > Webform** from the admin menu.
Create a new webform here. After this is saved, you can add the needed form elements.

This new webform is a node and will be listed in the content list page. If you want to render this webform as a block, Go to particular **webform, > Edit > Form settings** and in the Advanced settings tab, Check the "**Available as block**" checkbox.

Hope this helps..